# Set attribute for dynamicaly created element

Tags: javascript, html

We have use the following code snippet to create the `div` element in `JavaScript` plugin.

Code Snippet:

```
var temp = document.createElement('div');
```

But I cannot apply the style to this div. Can you please any look into this and provide suggestions for the following things. That would be very helpful for us.

- How to add Class for the created div?
- How to apply the style to that particular div?
- How to invoke the onscroll event for that div?

Comment: This is 3 questions all of which are duplicates, multiple times duplicate and even bing can find them.  Are we reputation farming here?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var temp = document.createElement('div');
temp.className = "yourclass";
temp.style.cssText = 'width:100px; height:100px'; //example
temp.onscroll = function() 
{ 
 alert('on scroll');
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/q6CMz/)

Answer (score 0):

[edit]
here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NHBr2/

you have now created the 'div' in your temp variable. In order to style this use this code.

Inline styles:

```
temp.setAttributes('style','width:100px;');
```

Adding a class:

```
temp.setAttributes('class','myClass');
```

Adding an ID:

```
temp.setAttributes('id','MyID');
```

Adding an Evenet:

```
temp.setAttributes('OnMouseWheel','myFunction(e);');
```

Comment: Do you mean `setAttribute` (singular)?

Comment: Thank you for your fast response . I will check the provided solution in our side.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var ele = document.createElement('div')
var id = 'temp'
ele.setAttribute('id', id)
```

Result in

```
<div id="temp"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## I recommend you take a look at the very basics of JavaScript in order to understand its functionality.

If you take a look at a small beginners tutorial for JavaScript, you learn most of the things you asked. They are very, very basic and should be searched for, rather than asked on stackoverflow. [Simply use google like this](https://www.google.de/search?q=javascript%20add%20class). Not so hard, is it?

But still, here are the answers to your questions. I know there are several ways of doing certain things. The following code snippets should work in all common browsers.

### Adding a class

To set an element's class, you can use the `setAttribute` method.

```
temp.setAttribute("class", "myclass");
```

### Applying styles

Every element has a `style` property that you can use to change anything you could change with CSS.

```
temp.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
temp.style.color = "#FFFFFF";
temp.style.fontSize = "24pt";
```

### Listening for events

You can add event listeners to an element either using the `onsomething` properties or `attachEvent` (Internet Explorer) and `addEventListener` (other Browsers).

#### Method 1 - onsomething properties:

Using the `onscroll` property of an element, you can apply **one** event listener at a time. It's the simplest method and supported by all browsers.

```
temp.onscroll = function(e) {
    // Do something
};
```

#### Method 2 - attachEvent and addEventListener:

Using `addEventListener`, you can apply **multiple** event listeners if needed. Most of the time, this is the preferred way. Older versions of Internet Explorer don't support `addEventlistener`, you therefore have to use `attachEvent` in this case.

```
// Check if the browser supports addEventListener
if (temp.addEventListener) {
    // If it does support addEventListener, use it
    temp.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
} else if (temp.attachEvent) {
    // If it does not support addEventListener, use attachEvent instead
    temp.attachEvent("onScroll", onScroll);
}

function onScroll(event) {
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var temp = document.createElement('div');   
temp.setAttribute('class', 'someClassName');
temp.setAttribute('Id', 'MyDiv');
```

you can set any css properties to assign class which is in this case 'someClassName', similarly you can invoke any function targeting assigned Id which is "myDiv"

hope this helps